# Problem getting property type through MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().ReflectedType;

Tags: .net, reflection, types, properties

I'm calling a generic method in some of my properties (to fill proxy classes made by NHibernate although this is not important right now)

To do this i want he type of the Property and pass this to a method which does it's magic, some of these properties however are "nested" Meaning for example the Address property will have this but the Country property of the Address also has this functionality.

The problem i seem to be getting is that due to the fact the Address getter is triggering the Country Getter, when i call MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().ReflectedType; in my Country property it returns Address as it's type, eventhough the type of the property in question in actually Country.

Here are some code snippets:

```
public virtual Country Country
        {
            get
            {
                _country = Backoffice.Library.Serialization.Reflection.GetPossiblyProxyProperty(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().ReflectedType, _country);

                return _country;
            }
            set { _country = value; }
        }
```

I'm pretty clueless as to why this would return the wrong Type, i really would like this to be as generic as possibly, i could ofc just do a typeof(Country) but then i'd have to set that for all my properties which sucks :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for the property's *return type*, you should use `MethodInfo.ReturnType` and not `ReflectedType`...

Comment: Yeah, i figured that out about 10 minutes after posting, for some reason it returns a MethodBase object, which if i cast it to MethodInfo will allow me to get the ReturnType property. It does not have this on the MethodBase though which through me off.